# Lua or Python binding with C++

Tags: c++, python, boost, lua, embedding

I have used Lua.NET on .NET platform and I  could call the .NET class/object from Lua and I could call the Lua from .NET Lua API interface. I did the same with the IronPython. I knew the how the .NET binding works.

Now I have a C++ project and I want to use the dynamic capabilities. I want to call C++ object which may not be possible from Lua so I may need to call some C API which makes call to C++. Meantime I want to call the Lua from C++.

We have configuration data which is best described in table like format in Lua or List & Dict like in Python. We need to enumerate these data structures defined in Lua/Python in C++.

When considering Lua to Python in C++ for two way calling, is Python have upper hand with Boost Python library? I don't have experience in Python/C++ binding. I don't have equal experience of using Python in C++ and calling Python from C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When considering Lua to Python in C++ for two way calling, is Python have upper hand with Boost Python library?

There are a few libraries that simplify the communication between C++ and Lua. One of them, [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html), is inspired by boost.python and is quite powerful and fairly easy to use.

Other C++ <-> Lua libraries to consider: [toLua++](http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/), [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to just use windows you could use C++/CLI a managed variant of C++. With C++/CLI you can easily mix managed and unmanaged code. You could call the managed classes from any .net language and the unmanaged (exported) functions from C.